# OpenMMClassification 1.X version crash on Colab

Tags: python, pytorch, classification

I tried to use MMClassification 0.X version with the same dataset it can work. However, using the 1.X version I keep on facing crash on google colab.

I have looked through the sample they provided and the only different from mine and theirs are the dataset, how they load their data through annotation file (which I uses the folder structure instead), and also the output node size which is 30 for my classes.

Here is my code for the model initialization:

```
from mmengine import Config, ConfigDict
from mmengine.runner import Runner

base_cfg = Config.fromfile(config_file)

# ------ model settings ------
# Modify the number of classes in the head.
model = base_cfg.model
model.head.num_classes = 30

# Load the pre-trained model's checkpoint.
model.backbone.init_cfg = dict(type='Pretrained', checkpoint=checkpoint_file, prefix='backbone')

# ----- data settings ------
train_dataloader = dict(
    batch_size=8,
    num_workers=2,
    dataset=dict(
        type='CustomDataset',
        data_prefix='/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Demo/Classification/agriculture/agriculture/train',
        classes=listFolderName,
        pipeline=base_cfg.train_dataloader.dataset.pipeline,
    ),
    sampler=dict(type='DefaultSampler', shuffle=True),
)

val_dataloader = dict(
    batch_size=8,
    num_workers=2,
    dataset=dict(
        type='CustomDataset',
        data_prefix='/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Demo/Classification/agriculture/agriculture/val',
        ann_file="",
        classes=listFolderName,
        pipeline=base_cfg.train_dataloader.dataset.pipeline,
    ),
    sampler=dict(type='DefaultSampler', shuffle=False),
)

# Specify the normalization parameters in the data preprocessor.
data_preprocessor = dict(mean=[124.508, 116.050, 106.438], std=[58.577, 57.310, 57.437], to_rgb=True)

# Specify the validation metric
val_evaluator = dict(type='Accuracy', topk=1)

# ------ schedule settings ------
# Specify the optimizer
optim_wrapper = dict(
    optimizer=dict(type='SGD', lr=0.005, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0001),
    clip_grad=None,
)

# Specify the learning rate scheduler
param_scheduler = dict(type='StepLR', by_epoch=True, step_size=1, gamma=0.1)

# Specify the training epochs
train_cfg = dict(by_epoch=True, max_epochs=2)
val_cfg = dict()  # To use the default validation settings.

# logger settings
logger = dict(type='LoggerHook', interval=10)

runner = Runner(
    # Common settings
    model=model,
    default_scope='mmcls',
    work_dir=r'/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Demo/Classification/agriculture/work_dir',
    experiment_name='mobilenet-v2_agriculture_1.XMMclassification',
    default_hooks=dict(logger=logger),
    # Training settings
    train_dataloader=train_dataloader,
    train_cfg=train_cfg,
    optim_wrapper=optim_wrapper,
    param_scheduler=param_scheduler,
    # Validation settings
    val_dataloader=val_dataloader,
    val_cfg=val_cfg,
    val_evaluator=val_evaluator,
)
```

[Crash everytime on the runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2QEb.png)

Below here is the log file that I generate it after it crashed

```
2023/02/11 08:47:27 - mmengine - INFO - 
------------------------------------------------------------
System environment:
    sys.platform: linux
    Python: 3.8.10 (default, Nov 14 2022, 12:59:47) [GCC 9.4.0]
    CUDA available: True
    numpy_random_seed: 146850278
    GPU 0: Tesla T4
    CUDA_HOME: /usr/local/cuda
    NVCC: Cuda compilation tools, release 11.6, V11.6.124
    GCC: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
    PyTorch: 1.13.1+cu116
    PyTorch compiling details: PyTorch built with:
  - GCC 9.3
  - C++ Version: 201402
  - Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 2020.0.0 Product Build 20191122 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications
  - Intel(R) MKL-DNN v2.6.0 (Git Hash 52b5f107dd9cf10910aaa19cb47f3abf9b349815)
  - OpenMP 201511 (a.k.a. OpenMP 4.5)
  - LAPACK is enabled (usually provided by MKL)
  - NNPACK is enabled
  - CPU capability usage: AVX2
  - CUDA Runtime 11.6
  - NVCC architecture flags: -gencode;arch=compute_37,code=sm_37;-gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-gencode;arch=compute_60,code=sm_60;-gencode;arch=compute_70,code=sm_70;-gencode;arch=compute_75,code=sm_75;-gencode;arch=compute_80,code=sm_80;-gencode;arch=compute_86,code=sm_86
  - CuDNN 8.3.2  (built against CUDA 11.5)
  - Magma 2.6.1
  - Build settings: BLAS_INFO=mkl, BUILD_TYPE=Release, CUDA_VERSION=11.6, CUDNN_VERSION=8.3.2, CXX_COMPILER=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/bin/c++, CXX_FLAGS= -fabi-version=11 -Wno-deprecated -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -DUSE_PTHREADPOOL -fopenmp -DNDEBUG -DUSE_KINETO -DUSE_FBGEMM -DUSE_QNNPACK -DUSE_PYTORCH_QNNPACK -DUSE_XNNPACK -DSYMBOLICATE_MOBILE_DEBUG_HANDLE -DEDGE_PROFILER_USE_KINETO -O2 -fPIC -Wno-narrowing -Wall -Wextra -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-type-limits -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wunused-local-typedefs -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-result -Wno-strict-overflow -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-psabi -Wno-error=pedantic -Wno-error=redundant-decls -Wno-error=old-style-cast -fdiagnostics-color=always -faligned-new -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-math-errno -fno-trapping-math -Werror=format -Werror=cast-function-type -Wno-stringop-overflow, LAPACK_INFO=mkl, PERF_WITH_AVX=1, PERF_WITH_AVX2=1, PERF_WITH_AVX512=1, TORCH_VERSION=1.13.1, USE_CUDA=ON, USE_CUDNN=ON, USE_EXCEPTION_PTR=1, USE_GFLAGS=OFF, USE_GLOG=OFF, USE_MKL=ON, USE_MKLDNN=ON, USE_MPI=OFF, USE_NCCL=ON, USE_NNPACK=ON, USE_OPENMP=ON, USE_ROCM=OFF, 

    TorchVision: 0.14.1+cu116
    OpenCV: 4.6.0
    MMEngine: 0.5.0

Runtime environment:
    dist_cfg: {'backend': 'nccl'}
    seed: None
    Distributed launcher: none
    Distributed training: False
    GPU number: 1
------------------------------------------------------------

2023/02/11 08:47:27 - mmengine - INFO - Config:


2023/02/11 08:47:27 - mmengine - WARNING - The "vis_backend" registry in mmcls did not set import location. Fallback to call `mmcls.utils.register_all_modules` instead.
2023/02/11 08:47:28 - mmengine - INFO - Distributed training is not used, all SyncBatchNorm (SyncBN) layers in the model will be automatically reverted to BatchNormXd layers if they are used.
2023/02/11 08:47:28 - mmengine - WARNING - The "hook" registry in mmcls did not set import location. Fallback to call `mmcls.utils.register_all_modules` instead.
2023/02/11 08:47:28 - mmengine - INFO - Hooks will be executed in the following order:
before_run:
(VERY_HIGH   ) RuntimeInfoHook                    
(BELOW_NORMAL) LoggerHook                         
 -------------------- 
before_train:
(VERY_HIGH   ) RuntimeInfoHook                    
(NORMAL      ) IterTimerHook                      
(VERY_LOW    ) CheckpointHook                     
 -------------------- 
before_train_epoch:
(VERY_HIGH   ) RuntimeInfoHook                    
(NORMAL      ) IterTimerHook                      
(NORMAL      ) DistSamplerSeedHook                
 -------------------- 
before_train_iter:
(VERY_HIGH   ) RuntimeInfoHook                    
(NORMAL      ) IterTimerHook                      
 -------------------- 
after_train_iter:
(VERY_HIGH   ) RuntimeInfoHook                    
(NORMAL      ) IterTimerHook                      
(BELOW_NORMAL) LoggerHook                         
(LOW         ) ParamSchedulerHook                 
(VERY_LOW    ) CheckpointHook                     
 -------------------- 
after_train_epoch:
(NORMAL      ) IterTimerHook                      
(LOW         ) ParamSchedulerHook                 
(VERY_LOW    ) CheckpointHook                     
 -------------------- 
before_val_epoch:
(NORMAL      ) IterTimerHook                      
 -------------------- 
before_val_iter:
(NORMAL      ) IterTimerHook                      
 -------------------- 
after_val_iter:
(NORMAL      ) IterTimerHook                      
(BELOW_NORMAL) LoggerHook                         
 -------------------- 
after_val_epoch:
(VERY_HIGH   ) RuntimeInfoHook                    
(NORMAL      ) IterTimerHook                      
(BELOW_NORMAL) LoggerHook                         
(LOW         ) ParamSchedulerHook                 
(VERY_LOW    ) CheckpointHook                     
 -------------------- 
before_test_epoch:
(NORMAL      ) IterTimerHook                      
 -------------------- 
before_test_iter:
(NORMAL      ) IterTimerHook                      
 -------------------- 
after_test_iter:
(NORMAL      ) IterTimerHook                      
(BELOW_NORMAL) LoggerHook                         
 -------------------- 
after_test_epoch:
(VERY_HIGH   ) RuntimeInfoHook                    
(NORMAL      ) IterTimerHook                      
(BELOW_NORMAL) LoggerHook                         
 -------------------- 
after_run:
(BELOW_NORMAL) LoggerHook                         
 -------------------- 
2023/02/11 08:48:19 - mmengine - WARNING - The "dataset" registry in mmcls did not set import location. Fallback to call `mmcls.utils.register_all_modules` instead.
2023/02/11 08:48:19 - mmengine - WARNING - The "transform" registry in mmcls did not set import location. Fallback to call `mmcls.utils.register_all_modules` instead.
2023/02/11 08:48:23 - mmengine - WARNING - The "data sampler" registry in mmcls did not set import location. Fallback to call `mmcls.utils.register_all_modules` instead.
2023/02/11 08:48:23 - mmengine - WARNING - The "optimizer wrapper constructor" registry in mmcls did not set import location. Fallback to call `mmcls.utils.register_all_modules` instead.
2023/02/11 08:48:23 - mmengine - WARNING - The "optimizer" registry in mmcls did not set import location. Fallback to call `mmcls.utils.register_all_modules` instead.
2023/02/11 08:48:23 - mmengine - WARNING - The "optimizer_wrapper" registry in mmcls did not set import location. Fallback to call `mmcls.utils.register_all_modules` instead.
2023/02/11 08:48:23 - mmengine - WARNING - The "parameter scheduler" registry in mmcls did not set import location. Fallback to call `mmcls.utils.register_all_modules` instead.
2023/02/11 08:48:26 - mmengine - WARNING - The "metric" registry in mmcls did not set import location. Fallback to call `mmcls.utils.register_all_modules` instead.
2023/02/11 08:48:29 - mmengine - WARNING - The "weight initializer" registry in mmcls did not set import location. Fallback to call `mmcls.utils.register_all_modules` instead.
2023/02/11 08:48:29 - mmengine - INFO - load backbone in model from: https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth
Name of parameter - Initialization information

backbone.conv1.conv.weight - torch.Size([32, 3, 3, 3]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.conv1.bn.weight - torch.Size([32]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.conv1.bn.bias - torch.Size([32]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer1.0.conv.0.conv.weight - torch.Size([32, 1, 3, 3]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer1.0.conv.0.bn.weight - torch.Size([32]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer1.0.conv.0.bn.bias - torch.Size([32]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer1.0.conv.1.conv.weight - torch.Size([16, 32, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer1.0.conv.1.bn.weight - torch.Size([16]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer1.0.conv.1.bn.bias - torch.Size([16]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.0.conv.0.conv.weight - torch.Size([96, 16, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.0.conv.0.bn.weight - torch.Size([96]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.0.conv.0.bn.bias - torch.Size([96]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.0.conv.1.conv.weight - torch.Size([96, 1, 3, 3]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.0.conv.1.bn.weight - torch.Size([96]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.0.conv.1.bn.bias - torch.Size([96]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.0.conv.2.conv.weight - torch.Size([24, 96, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.0.conv.2.bn.weight - torch.Size([24]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.0.conv.2.bn.bias - torch.Size([24]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.1.conv.0.conv.weight - torch.Size([144, 24, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.1.conv.0.bn.weight - torch.Size([144]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.1.conv.0.bn.bias - torch.Size([144]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.1.conv.1.conv.weight - torch.Size([144, 1, 3, 3]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.1.conv.1.bn.weight - torch.Size([144]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.1.conv.1.bn.bias - torch.Size([144]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.1.conv.2.conv.weight - torch.Size([24, 144, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.1.conv.2.bn.weight - torch.Size([24]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer2.1.conv.2.bn.bias - torch.Size([24]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer3.0.conv.0.conv.weight - torch.Size([144, 24, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer3.0.conv.0.bn.weight - torch.Size([144]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer3.0.conv.0.bn.bias - torch.Size([144]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer3.0.conv.1.conv.weight - torch.Size([144, 1, 3, 3]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer3.0.conv.1.bn.weight - torch.Size([144]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer3.0.conv.1.bn.bias - torch.Size([144]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer3.0.conv.2.conv.weight - torch.Size([32, 144, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer3.0.conv.2.bn.weight - torch.Size([32]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 



backbone.layer4.3.conv.2.bn.bias - torch.Size([64]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.0.conv.0.conv.weight - torch.Size([384, 64, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.0.conv.0.bn.weight - torch.Size([384]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.0.conv.0.bn.bias - torch.Size([384]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.0.conv.1.conv.weight - torch.Size([384, 1, 3, 3]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.0.conv.1.bn.weight - torch.Size([384]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.0.conv.1.bn.bias - torch.Size([384]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.0.conv.2.conv.weight - torch.Size([96, 384, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.0.conv.2.bn.weight - torch.Size([96]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.0.conv.2.bn.bias - torch.Size([96]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.1.conv.0.conv.weight - torch.Size([576, 96, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.1.conv.0.bn.weight - torch.Size([576]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.1.conv.0.bn.bias - torch.Size([576]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.1.conv.1.conv.weight - torch.Size([576, 1, 3, 3]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.1.conv.1.bn.weight - torch.Size([576]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.1.conv.1.bn.bias - torch.Size([576]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.1.conv.2.conv.weight - torch.Size([96, 576, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.1.conv.2.bn.weight - torch.Size([96]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.1.conv.2.bn.bias - torch.Size([96]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.2.conv.0.conv.weight - torch.Size([576, 96, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.2.conv.0.bn.weight - torch.Size([576]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.2.conv.0.bn.bias - torch.Size([576]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.2.conv.1.conv.weight - torch.Size([576, 1, 3, 3]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.2.conv.1.bn.weight - torch.Size([576]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.2.conv.1.bn.bias - torch.Size([576]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.2.conv.2.conv.weight - torch.Size([96, 576, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.2.conv.2.bn.weight - torch.Size([96]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer5.2.conv.2.bn.bias - torch.Size([96]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.0.conv.0.conv.weight - torch.Size([576, 96, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.0.conv.0.bn.weight - torch.Size([576]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.0.conv.0.bn.bias - torch.Size([576]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.0.conv.1.conv.weight - torch.Size([576, 1, 3, 3]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.0.conv.1.bn.weight - torch.Size([576]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.0.conv.1.bn.bias - torch.Size([576]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.0.conv.2.conv.weight - torch.Size([160, 576, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.0.conv.2.bn.weight - torch.Size([160]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.0.conv.2.bn.bias - torch.Size([160]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.1.conv.0.conv.weight - torch.Size([960, 160, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.1.conv.0.bn.weight - torch.Size([960]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.1.conv.0.bn.bias - torch.Size([960]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.1.conv.1.conv.weight - torch.Size([960, 1, 3, 3]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.1.conv.1.bn.weight - torch.Size([960]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.1.conv.1.bn.bias - torch.Size([960]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.1.conv.2.conv.weight - torch.Size([160, 960, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.1.conv.2.bn.weight - torch.Size([160]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer6.1.conv.2.bn.bias - torch.Size([160]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 



backbone.layer7.0.conv.2.conv.weight - torch.Size([320, 960, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer7.0.conv.2.bn.weight - torch.Size([320]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.layer7.0.conv.2.bn.bias - torch.Size([320]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.conv2.conv.weight - torch.Size([1280, 320, 1, 1]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.conv2.bn.weight - torch.Size([1280]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

backbone.conv2.bn.bias - torch.Size([1280]): 
PretrainedInit: load from https://download.openmmlab.com/mmclassification/v0/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_batch256_imagenet_20200708-3b2dc3af.pth 

head.fc.weight - torch.Size([30, 1280]): 
NormalInit: mean=0, std=0.01, bias=0 

head.fc.bias - torch.Size([30]): 
NormalInit: mean=0, std=0.01, bias=0 
2023/02/11 08:48:29 - mmengine - INFO - Checkpoints will be saved to /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Demo/Classification/agriculture/work_dir.
```

I tried several times including using CPU and placing the ann_file as None instead of empty string (which it worked on 0.X version). Would like to know why would the crash occur? Is it really because of colab limited resources or something wrong with my implementation.

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"? Your image just shows warning and info logging messages. It's not clear what kind of answer you are looking for, as you have not stated a question.

Comment: Yes it just show colab crash with error code:  Your session crashed. Automatically restarting. I have updated my question